# How to create an object using all keywords and values of a different object?

Tags: python, object

How can I create an object, while also passing to its `__init__` all the keywords and their values of another object? Basically this:

```
class Person():
    instances = []
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
        __class__.instances.append(self)

class TemplatePerson():
    instances = []
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
        __class__.instances.append(self)

def foo(template):
    # I want this function to basically execute what would be:
    # Person(name="Alice",surname="Bobbette")
    # except dynamically for all the keywords and values the template object could have
    pass

foo(TemplatePerson(name="Alice",surname="Bobbette"))
```

I stumbled upon `__dict__`, but don't know how to utilize it. It's important that all the keywords are passed to the new object on its initialization, rather than do something like:

```
Person.name="Alice"
Person.surname="Bobbette
```

because my `Person.__init__` is a mess ;)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: Why not to use inheritance?

Comment: Using `__dict__` may be convenient from a "saving keystrokes" perspective, but it will make your class dangerously susceptible to typo bugs.